# Magento 2 : Check if method exist in class

Tags: magento2, store-credit

I am getting below error

```
Magento 2 : Call to a member function getCustomerIsGuest() on null error
```

on `Magento\CustomerBalance\Model\Balance` class

In local environment
on `protected function _ensureCustomer()` method i get order data by $this->getOrder()
but in live it causes error, i am not sure if `$this->getOrder()` method exist for this class and in `_ensureCustomer()` method.

Any advice or thoughts ?

Comment: Any advice or thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

```
class A{
    public function foo(){
        echo "foo";
    }

    public function bar(){
        if(method_exists($this, 'foo')){
            echo "method exists";
        }else{
            echo "method does not exist";
        }
    }
}

$obj = new A;
$obj->bar();
```

but in your case the method or function you are passing on an object is Null.
Wrap it to `is_null($oject)`

Might this help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when i add condition it prints method not exist but on using it it gives output

if(method_exists($this, 'getOrder')){
                        echo "method exists";
                    }else{
                        echo "method does not exist";
                    }
                    echo $this->getOrder()->getId(); //i am getting data here even if it shows method not exist
                    exit;

Comment: Any advice or thoughts ?

Comment: Then your getOrder() is not in the same class it is in another class that you have extended and see I have added the is_null method because you are looking wrong thing, please ensure you are looking it into right stuff

Comment: Its not getting into is_null , so data is their.
Actually i just not want to avoid error but find where the getorder method is declared

Comment: If you use PHP Strom or VS code then add your source code to editor WS and right click and the chose go to definition

Comment: Please complete this one getCustomerIsGuest() what is there in prefix and suffix eg: $this->getOrder()->getCustomerIsGuest();

Comment: yes its $this->getOrder()->getCustomerIsGuest()

Comment: Is their any extension required for method definition in Vs code ?

Comment: Try to install PHP IntelliSense and PHP namespace resolver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121064/discussion-between-devhs-and-nilesh-dubey).

Comment: Thankyou very much, i had installed extensions & tried to "go to defination" in vs code editor on $this->getOrder() but it shows "no defination found"

Comment: Hi, in my local environment i am getting data but not in production.
any thoughts what can be the issue ?

Comment: I am guessing - because of FPC or may be because of timeout